# What is the best data type to store Kilogram in Java?

Tags: java, types, double, bigdecimal

I am creating a Class that have to deal and store data about Kilogram.

This:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="raw_material_harvest_projection", schema = "dbo")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RawMaterialHarvestProjection {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "raw_material")
    private RawMaterial rawMaterial;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Double quantity; //this is the field that store Kilogram

}
```

But I am thinking that if I use `Double` I can have some troubles in some calculus and if I use `BigDecimal` I'll be stuck with only two squares after the comma.

What is the best way to do it:

Comment: If a precision of 0.001 kilogram is good enough for you, you can simply store the value in *grams*. That way you could use an `Integer`.

Comment: *and if I use BigDecimal I'll be stuck with only two squares after the comma.* Please clarify. That class has arbitrary precision, i.e. *you* can choose what it is

Comment: Grams is quite a good idea as that *is* the SI unit but `long` might be better for amounts, especially if you're going agricultural

Comment: Anyway, it is hard to guess when it's not clear what scope your harvests have: plant pot or nationwide.